# Logging deleted records in a PostgreSQL (plpgsql) function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'd like to log rows deleted by a `DELETE` statement in a plpgsql function, and I'm trying to use the `RETURNING *` clause to do it. Unfortunately this doesn't work by itself since the result of the query has no destination. How do I capture these rows and log them with `RAISE NOTICE`?

E.g.

```sql
-- some plpgsql code
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE x=y RETURNING *; -- this fails
-- some plpgsql code
```

I've tried some variants of `... RETURNING * INTO var` but no luck. Don't know what type the `var` variable should be.

Transactional considerations are not an issue - just want to log those records.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a cursor:

```
create table test (a int, b int);
insert into test VALUES (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_delete() RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
  deleted_row_cursor CURSOR FOR DELETE FROM test WHERE a < 3 RETURNING *;
BEGIN
    FOR deleted_row in deleted_row_cursor LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE '%', deleted_row;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

select * from test_delete();
psql: NOTICE:  (1,2)
psql: NOTICE:  (2,3)
 test_delete
-------------

(1 row)
```